# calculating a checksum within a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to validate the checksum for each row of data

I have a row of data like this:

```py
cstype = np.dtype = ([("data16",'<u2',(4,))]) #binary array style is Uint16

thisRow = np.frombuffer(records[2],cstype)     # a record

thisRow ([4,5,6,15])
```

How to check the last element is the sum of the first 3 elements ?

Comment: What about `thisRow[:-1].sum() == thisRow[-1]` ?

Comment: IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed

Comment: Strange. It works with `thisRow = np.array([4,5,6,15])`. So `thisRow` is likely ill-formed. What is supposed to be `records` in your example?

Comment: records = np.fromfile(f,rtype) #reading a binary file

Comment: rtype = np.dtype([
    ("Axis0", np.int16,(4,)),
    ("Axis1", np.int16,(4,)),
    ("Axis2", np.int16,(4,)),
    ("Axis3", np.int16,(4,)),
    ("Axis4", np.int16,(4,)),
    ("Axis5", np.int16,(4,)),
    ("Time",'<u4'),
    ("Degrees",np.int16,(3,)),
    ("Blanks",np.int16,(2,)),
    ("CheckSum",np.int16,(1,))
])

Comment: Its a TimeStamped Acceleration/Gyro set with a checksum on each record

Comment: updating to a new question, adding your code

Comment: done, can you check this one ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70387820/numpy-trying-to-verify-a-row-checksum